# How to edit Sublime Text 2 Macros

Tags: windows-8, macros, sublime-text-2

How can I edit Sublime Text 2 Macros? What program to use to open the file (example - MyMacro.sublime-macro)?

Also, how can I delay the keyboard typing in playing the macro?

I hit record macro, then start typing a paragraph template, it works good, but when playing the macro or executing it, what I want is to see the words/characters as they are being typed?

Of course I won't able to see it as it type each character because its fast. Is there a way to delay it, like 10 characters / second.

How to delay and make the macro execution slower?

Answer (score 0):

`.sublime-macro` files are in JSON format, and they can be edited directly in Sublime. If you want specialized syntax highlighting, install the [`AAAPackageDev`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AAAPackageDev) package from [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io), along with the [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) (full disclosure: I'm Neon's maintainer).

Macros are executed all at once - there is no way to "slow them down". You could conceivably write a plugin in Python that would read in some text from a file, then print it out slowly, but I really don't see the point.